# Css main tag resize when aside min-width: 200px

Tags: html, css

I have a header, main, aside and footer elements. The main is my content and the aside is on the right and it supposed to be a sidebar. They are `20-80%` of the screen width.

I want to give `200px min-width` for my aside, but how can i tell the main content to size itself and give enough space for my aside when `20%` would be under `200px`?

My question isn't how to expand a div's space to take remaining width but only take remaining width when my aside would be under 200px because of the 20% width.

```
    <body>
        <header id="main-header">
            it's 100%
        </header>
        <main>
            it's 80%, display: inline-block;
            need to be resized if 20% is under 200px
            <div id="main-content">
                it's 100%
            </div>
        </main>
        <aside id="right-content">
            its 20%, display: inline-block; min-width: 200px;
        </aside>
        <footer id="main-footer">
            it's 100%
        </footer>
    <body>
```

Css code:

```
*{
    overflow: hidden;   

}

body{
    background-color: rgb(44, 36, 22);
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#main-header{
    background-color: rgb( 69, 56, 35); 
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 5;
}

body main{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 80%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#main-content{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(44, 36, 22);
    color: white;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 500px;
    float: left;
    border: 2px solid white;

}

#right-content{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1px solid white;
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 200px;
    float: right;
    border: 2px solid white;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: can you actually post your css?

Comment: Try using http://jsfiddle.net/ and post all relevant code there. It is easiest for us to view, test and update your code.

Comment: Jacob Gray:
I did, hope nothing missing. 
jerseyetr:
Didn't use it yet, but noticed a lot of people do, i'll check it, thank you. :)

Comment: I checked that question what ,,already answered my question". Dont know if it's automatic or someone suggested it(im newbie on this website), but my problem is not fix sidebar. I want fix sidebar only if 20% of my page width is under 200px; I want responsive website but i need at least 200px for my aside.

Comment: I edited my question but still marked as duplicated. I don't want fixed aside.